# Linear Mixed model with lmer in R. How to formulate the within subject factors?

Tags: r, mixed-model, modeling, lme4-nlme

I would like to know which of these formulas is better for answering my research questions (see below) and explain why, or maybe someone can suggest me another one.

```
model1 = lmer(EEG ~ Age + Gender + Eyes + Training + EEGLocation + (1 | Subject/Eyes /Training), data = data, REML=FALSE)

model2 = lmer(EEG ~ Age + Gender + Eyes + Training + EEGLocation + (1 + Eyes +Training | Subject), data = data, REML=FALSE)
```

My problem is that I am not sure about how to include in the model the within subject factors (EEG locations, Eyes condition, Before/After Training) and the between subject factors (age and gender). I don’t know if I should include the subjects as random factors and if Eyes condition, EEG locations and Before/After training are nested in subject.

The distribution of the raw data of the DV is approximately a log normal distribution.

DV: EEG activity.

Between subject factors: Age, Gender.

Within subject factors: EEG locations, Eyes condition, Before/After Training.

Age: continuous variable (between 4 – 68). 
Gender: 2 levels (female, male). 
EEG locations: 2 levels (C3, C4). 
Eyes condition: 2 levels (Closed, Open). 
Training condition: 2 levels (Before, After).

Research Questions:

• Is there a significant change of the EEG activity in the expected direction after training?

• Is this effect dependent on Age, Gender, EEG location and/or Eyes condition?

Comment: Hmm.. is you say that `EEG` is log-normal maybe you should consider using the log tranformed `EGG` readings. As the lognormal distribution is not a member of the exponential family of distributions you can't use a generalized linear mixed models for it.

Comment: I found the following so I thought I would not need to transform the data? Do you disagree?
"If your data best fit the lognormal distribution, do not transform them. This is true for any type of transformation you might apply to your data to make them normal. Recent statistics literature has entirely changed stance on this matter, however, because transformation makes interpretation of model results more difficult, and it makes mischief with the variance of the transformed variable." [link](http://ase.tufts.edu/gsc/gradresources/guidetomixedmodelsinr/mixed%20model%20guide.html)

Comment: I do not fully disagree with this passage but I think it is heavy-handed. Obviously the interpretation of your coefficients will change but this is not something unheard of. Try using `glmer` with `family= gaussian(link='log')` first. Notice that the *mean of the log-transformed variable* is not always the same as the *log of the variable's mean*; I think this is what prompts the author to say this. I checked the references published after 1997 in the link you provide; I could not find this statement being supported even in Lindsey-Jones 1998 that clearly makes comments about the lognormal.